# Filter 2 Tables by Rownames

Tags: r, matrix, filter

as you can see in the Tabs I have a clinical data frame and a heatmap data frame.

Both have their rows consisting of Patient_IDs. The clinical data frame has been filtered to female with approximately 130 observations. The heat map data frame has all patients, which means males and females. When trying to create a heat map, the amount of observations from bot data set must be similar. Now comes my question, what is the best way to Filter the Patient_ID in the heatmap data frame to the Patient_IDs in the click data frame?

what I found(unfortunately there is no column name for patient ID):

```
heatmap <- heatmap%>% filter(heatmap$c(0) %in% clinical$c(0)
```

Please be merciful, this is my first month with R-Studios.

Heatmap Data Frame

[image]

Clinical data frame

[image]

Comment: Could you provide actual data with `dput(head(heatmap))` and `dput(clinical)` instead of an image : it will be easier to help.

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rownames` to extract the rownames from a dataframe/matrix.

```
result <- heatmap[rownames(heatmap) %in% rownames(clinical), ]
```